# Java - recording and capturing

Tags: java, api, audio, record, capture

I am developing a small real-time application to record sound waves. It has two modules: recording , listening. 
here is how it should work :

1. The program starts listening.
2. A sound wave arrives.
3. The program recognizes that a signal has arrived, and starts
   recording it.
4. When the signal is over (no more loud sounds), the program stops
   recording and saves the result to a file.

So in order to recognize when the signal is over - we should listen to the wave (capture) along with recording, so we can detect when the sound is over.

In order to implement this, iv'e used the Java sound API, but i have one problem:

- **The target-data-line object is shared between the recording-thread and the capture-thread**. In this case, two threads are working on the same target-data-line : The capture and the recorder threads.
  which cases some real-time problems.

I have tried to open two target-data-lines, one for recording and one for capturing ,  but the program throws an exception when trying to open the second one.

How can i fix the problem ? 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a single thread which has exclusive access to the `TargetDataLine`. This thread can then generate events which your recording and listening thread can subscribe to.